# Insert another language in python input field

Tags: python, blender, hindi

**I am using Blender Game Engine**.  I have made input field using [BGUI](https://github.com/Moguri/bgui). I should be able to input Hindi rather than English in that field. I am looking for something like [SCIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_Common_Input_Method). But I couldn't find a way to do that. Please help.

Comment: user should input text from keyboard . SCIM in python for bgui field is an option?

Comment: guys what is unclear here?

Comment: This much is clear: Adding a comment here will not help grab anybody's attention -- it is only visible to those who visit this question. If you genuinely want us to pay attention, offer 50 points of your own reputation as a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

I seems clear that Blender does not have currently support to do this[1]. I did find there was support for Arabic, Urdu and Korean. None of the Indic languages are yet supported.

1. http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/1bjALquobSh881nFZHty